# Windows: 'Query User' command reporting idle time inaccurately (false positives)

Tags: batch-file, windows-command-prompt

I'm working with ten other sysadmins that sometimes forget to log out of servers (or even lock them). For two days or more, I've been trying to come up with a 'script' that'll check each server we manage for idle administrator accounts. If they've been idle for more than two days, I intend to **log them out** (not lock them).

If I could rely on the command '**Query User**', this would've been a finished project. But unfortunately, it appears that I cannot rely on that command. Here's some example output from a random server:

```
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 techyellow            console             4  Active      none   1/18/2017 10:35 AM
```

**TechYellow** has been on vacation since 1/19/2017 - it's been idle for **nearly four days** now. If I launch a VNC session, I can see - plain as day - Windows is logged in and I can do whatever I want with TechYellow's account; it's not even locked. Yet, my query thinks TechYellow is **Active**. I've confirmed that the same is true even if the account is locked - it still reports **Active** more often than not. This is just one example - I've been testing this command on several servers, and I've found that it provides false results more often than correct results, for a variety of different admin accounts.

Is there a better alternative to **Query User**? I've looked high and low, but everything I've found circles back to similar commands that all report falsely.

I just want to see if an admin is logged in and has been idle for two or more days. That's it! Anyone conquered this in the past?

Comment: Setting [Session Time Limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753112(v=ws.10).aspx), particularly _Set time limit for active but idle Terminal Services sessions_ via  Group Policy might help?